# How to find all IP addresses within a specific range?

Tags: regex, linux

I'm trying to find all IP address in Linux (in all files) in this format:

192.168.X.X

X is from 0 to 255.

I tried this:

```
grep -E –r -n '(192)\.(168)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)' .
```

It works correctly... but, it also gives this IP address: 192.168.X.260 as 192.168.X.26 by ignoring the 0 at the end.

What should I do to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Pierre.Vriens. What happened to your Drupal account on SE? I couldn't see you for a while. Happy to see you here :) And of course the "perfect" answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What should I do to fix this?

You should make use of a tool that can perform comparisons:

```
awk -F. '$1==192 && $2==168 && $3>=1 && $3<=255 && $4>=1 && $4<=255' inputfile
```

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, in order to perform this for all files you can use `find`:

```
find /path -type f -exec awk -F. '$1==192 && $2==168 && $3>=1 && $3<=255 && $4>=1 && $4<=255' {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working for a spesific file (inputfile). Is there a way to run this for all files in Linux.

Comment: @herci Use it with find: `find /path -type f -exec awk -F. '$1==192 && $2==168 && $3>=1 && $3<=255 && $4>=1 && $4<=255' {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
(192)\.(168)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[1]?[0-9]?[0-9])
```

Anyway you can use http://www.regexper.com to help you with regex :)

Comment: Unfortunately it's also not working correctly as mine. Thanks for the link.